Read Excel file via Apex/JS then display it in a Datatable
I am new to Salesforce development world so please bear with me. my client wants to upload an excel file (filled with existing contact records), read the data using apex/js, then display it in a datatable either via flow or LWC. I don't know how I can parse that excel data into Json or string. My company is not allowing me to download or install any node js or sheet library. I tried creating an LWC component that can upload file and read the excel file (I used a script then import it as a static resource), but I am not sure if it working. Please help. See code below:
<!-- fileupload.html -->
<template>
    <lightning-card title="Upload Excel File">
        <lightning-input type="file" name="file" accept=".xlsx, .xls" onchange={handleFileUpload}></lightning-input>
    </lightning-card>
</template>

<jsfile>
import { LightningElement, track } from 'lwc';
import { loadScript } from 'lightning/platformResourceLoader';
import XLSX from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/sheetjs';

export default class ECCMassSuspensionFileUpload extends LightningElement {
    @track contacts;
    @track selectedRows = [];
    columns = [
        { label: 'Name', fieldName: 'Name', type: 'text' },
        { label: 'Email', fieldName: 'Email', type: 'email' },
        // Add more columns as needed
    ];

    handleFileChange(event) {
        const file = event.target.files[0];
        if (file) {
            this.readExcelFile(file);
        }
    }

    async readExcelFile(file) {
        await loadScript(this, XLSX);
        const reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = (event) => {
            const data = new Uint8Array(event.target.result);
            const workbook = XLSX.read(data, { type: 'array' });
            const sheetName = workbook.SheetNames[0]; // Assuming data is in the first sheet
            const sheet = workbook.Sheets[sheetName];
            const parsedData = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(sheet, { header: 1 });
            this.contacts = parsedData.map((row, index) => ({ id: index, Name: row[0], Email: row[1] }));
        };
        reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
    }

    handleRowSelection(event) {
        this.selectedRows = event.detail.selectedRows;
    }
}

js-meta.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <apiVersion>59.0</apiVersion>
    <isExposed>true</isExposed>
    <targets>
        <target>lightning__FlowScreen</target>
    </targets>
    <targetConfigs>
        <targetConfig targets="lightning__FlowScreen">
            <property name="contacts" type="String" role="inputOnly"/>
        </targetConfig>
    </targetConfigs>
</LightningComponentBundle>

I tried using LWC and flow as well but I cannot make it work somehow. maybe apex can help to. I want to finish this by next week but my lead died so I don know what to do anymore.
